# Generalized convexity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a vector space. The positive-homogeneous function $\|\cdot\|$ is said to be a quasinorm
if $\|x+y\|\le K(\|x\|+\|y\|)$, for some $K\ge1$; it is a norm if $K=1$.

Question: 1. (terminology) if we drop the positive-homogeneity assumption and only assume that $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and satisfies $f(\frac12x+\frac12y)\le \frac{K}{2}[f(x)+f(y)]$, one might expect, by analogy, that this property be called "quasiconvexity" but it is not; the latter term is reserved for $f(\frac12x+\frac12y)\le \max\{f(x),f(y)\}$. Q: So what is the accepted term for this property?
2. What is known about maximizing a quasinorm (or, more generally, a "weakly convex" function $f$ in the sense of Q1) over a compact set -- say, in a finite-dimensional space? Are the maxima necessarily achieved at extreme points?

Comment: If you are one of those to whom the typographical difference between $||x||$ and $\|x\|$ is not conspicuous, look at the difference between $||x|| ||y||$ (coded as `||x|| ||y||`) and $\|x\|\|y\|$ (coded as `\|x\|\|y\|`). I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy -- looks nicer! Any pointers on either of the questions? :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the condition $f(\frac12x + \frac12y)\le \frac12 (f(x)+f(y))$ is sometimes called midpoint convexity.

Comment: Yes, and it's equivalent to classic convexity for continuous functions.